# Is there a term for someone restricting a discussion to a group of people?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation, debate

Is there a term for when someone in a discussion dismisses or excludes a group of people?
I think I've heard a term for "gating" the discussion but I can't find it.

For example:
"You can only appreciate this music if you have good speakers"

Thus that person would disregard anyone's opinion of the music if their speakers aren't deemed to be "good".

It's seen quite a bit in a variety of contexts and I've checked the standard lists of logical fallacies but I can't figure out the specific term to describe that style of discussion.

Comment: This probably belongs in English Language Stack. You can look up the definition of “clique”, but I am not sure that’s the word you are looking for.

Comment: Cliquish? Maybe.

Comment: Yep that's close, but more in the context of a discussion or debate?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "cherry picking," or anyhow, nebulously, "suppressed evidence." Cicero conveys to us a witty occasion of Diagoras of Melos pointing to the fallacy (to my knowledge, the earliest record of it) in his *De Natura Deorum* (III.89)

> Diagoras, named the Atheist, once came to Samothrace, and a certain
> friend said to him, "You who think that the gods disregard men's
> affairs, do you not remark all the votive pictures that prove how many
> persons have escaped the violence of the storm, and come safe to port,
> by dint of vows to the gods?" "That is so," replied Diagoras; "it is
> because there are nowhere any pictures of those who have been
> shipwrecked and drowned at sea."